# Rudin's proof of why $\bar{E}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

He says that for any point $p \in X, p \notin \bar{E}$, there is a neighborhood of $p$ that does not intersect $E$. True, but what if it intersects $E'$ (and not $E$)?  We need to handle that case too in order to prove that such a neighborhood is contained in $\bar{E}^c$.

EDIT: Answer: because if it intersected $E'$, that would imply it intersects $E$.

Comment: If it intersected $E'$ but not $E$, then you could take a point in the intersection, and a neighbourhood around it which does not intersect $E$, which is absurd.

Comment: Yeah, just thought of it a few seconds after and was going to add. Thanks for answering already. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because if it intersected E′, that would imply it intersects $E$.